Replace SimpleFieldSelect with Variable input on Dual Function
I am trying to replace the SimpleFieldSelect extension with Qlik's Variable input but am not able to get the Dual function to work properly to display those inputs.
Below is the dual function used in the data load editor:
    CalendarSelector:
       LOAD
           dual("Calendar Selection", SortOrder) as "~Calendar Selection",
           SortOrder,
           Formula
           Inline[
                  "Calendar Selection", SortOrder, Formula
                  "May contest",        1,         "num(COUNT({<Filter={'X'}>} DISTINCT Id),'#,##0')"
                  "June contest",       2,         "num(COUNT({<Filter={'Y'}>} DISTINCT Id),'#,##0')"
           ];

For the SimpleFieldSelect all I had to enter was =[~Calendar Selection]
For the Variable input I needed to create it as a variable so I created one vCalendarSelection =[~Calendar Selection] however when selection that as the variable for the dropdown nothing shows for selections but I would expect the 2 choices of May contest and June contest.

I didn't take from the question what you are actually trying to achieve, but I can say that this doesn't work the way you intend it to:

vCalendarSelection =[~Calendar Selection]

You are just saving the string "~Calendar Selection" in your variable not the field. To store the field values of ~Calendar Selection in vCalendarSelection you need to do this:
PrepareVariable:
Load Concat("~Calendar Selection", ' | ') as "calendar_select_concat"
Resident CalendarSelector
;

Let vCalendarSelection = Peek('calendar_select_concat', 0, 'PrepareVariable');

The resulting variable can be input in a Variable Input Object from the "Custom Objects" section in the frontend in the Dynamic Values Field like:

EDIT
To responde to your comment: It sounds like you need the ~Calendar Selection as a label and the SortOrder field is what you actually want to use in the frontend.
You can achieve it like this:
PrepareVariable:
Load Concat("SortOrder" & '~' & "~Calendar Selection", ' | ') as "calendar_select_concat"
Resident CalendarSelector
;

Now your users can chose between "May contest" and "June contest" in the drop-down menu, but what is actually assigned to vSelectedDate is the SortOrder.
Hope this helps.

What do you have vSelectedDate as then?

That's the variable that your selection is assigned to. To be used elsewhere in the app.

Now the dropdown looks correct but it is still not linking to the vSelectedDate = [~Calendar Selection]. Like the charts where I reference that SortOrder & Formula changes nothing if a formula is this: $(=replace(only({1<SortOrder={"$(=min(SortOrder))"}>} Formula), 'Filter', 'Filter'))

As I said in my answer: I don't know what you are trying to achieve. I don't know your charts either. But this way you assign the contents of ~Calendar Selection to a variable.

Yes your way does provide the string piece but my issue is that it is still not linking to the number piece of the dual functionality. So ultimately I would have one Variable Input object where the user would select either of those 2 string options and then based on the selection the chart metric uses a replace which uses the min SortOrder (the number portion of the dual function) for the differing filters in the set analysis.

Please refer to my edit
